# Failed updates disappear

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

I just installed Windows Server 2012 R2
I ran Windows Update and it found 42 updates. 
But something happend and it failed.

Then I ran Windows Update again, and under history I can see that almost every updates failed. 
But when i then checked for updates it only found 9 updates.

Where is the other updates that i originally found?
And how can I install them?

Regards
Michael

Comment: Have you checked to see if they exist under optional updates?

Comment: There is a "Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer" released nearly every month. The most recent one always replaces the older ones. Once you have the Feb 2015 IE update, you don't need the older ones.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, one of two things occurs:

1. These updates were found to be no longer necessary, so they failed and don't come back.
2. After a reboot or running a Windows update check again, they come back.

You can check the failure of the update and lookup the error code. You can get the error code in the History view. Double-click the failed update to get the details of the failure.